# Java Object Clone (additional class member) using Prototype, Builder Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, prototype

It is not easy to explain my issue.

JPA creates some complex objects for calculations, which are stored in a database.
We decided to set the results in a working copy of this objects.
This means for each object model we created a seperated working copy model file with the same fields but some other LocalDates values and new result fields.
When the calculation was starting the working copies are instantiated.
This approach is not the best i think.
I think of the prototype pattern to clone the object.
There i come to the problem how to add the new fields. How?
Instantion costs and ist creates lots of additionals model class files.
I only think of put the result field in the calculation data models as transient fields.
Maybe inner class or local class?
I also tried to use an interface as data bucket.
But thats not the realy purpose of interfaces and also it works only with many curious trick.
For Unit Tests and user input i think it is the best to use the builder pattern and then tell JPA to store the parent object, or not?

Comment: "_We decided to set the results in a working copy of this objects._" Why? Why not simply a `Result` class?

Comment: There is big complex object relationship with Lists and Sets One To Many etc. relationship. When i set the result i a new class i cant determine the right object e.g. in a list. So we bild the same structurefor these result and seperated these classes in a package.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but my answer was to long for a comment :(

There is big complex object relationship with Lists and Sets One To Many etc. relationship. When i set the result i a new class i cant determine the right object e.g. in a list. So we bild the same structurefor these result and seperated these classes in a package. Maybe it is possible to dont build the structure a second time with also references to the "basic classes". It should be sufficient to reference to each basic class a result class. It would only a little bit more navigation to get values from deeper classes. For a similiar use case there must be a best practise, or? Interfaces or sth. I very dislike the many classes for the result. Is it not possible to clone and add classmember to it for the result or to logical group easier or something like this?

It could be a solution for somebody:
http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2FIWorkingCopy.html

Here you will work with the Eclipse API and create IWorkingCopies.
For the described task toooo much.

Comment: Maybe the solution: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2FIWorkingCopy.html

Comment: You can edit your question to add this information (and then delete this answer).